# Installing gprof on Mac

Tags: homebrew

I would like to install GNU Profiler (gprof) on Mac. I tried to install `binutils` using Homebrew; however, the package that Homebrew installs from the following address does not have `gprof`.

```
http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/binutils/binutils-2.24.tar.gz
```

According to `binutils` website, it should have `gprof` in it.

```
http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/
```

Any suggestion for installing `gprof` is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

If you run `brew install -v binutils`, you will see this output flying by:

```
*** This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories:
     ld gas gprof
     (Any other directories should still work fine.)
```

In `configure.ac` there is

```
*-*-darwin*)
  noconfigdirs="$noconfigdirs ld gas gdb gprof"
  noconfigdirs="$noconfigdirs sim target-rda"
  ;;
```

So, `gprof` is not supported on OS X.

I think the preferred profiling tool is DTrace.

Comment: Thanks. Any other solution to get `gprof` to work?

Comment: @Javad do have any solution to gprof to work on OS X?

Comment: @Mohan Not really, I gave up on this.